# Error in upload image in registration page

Tags: node.js

trying to upload a file in my registration page but getting error.

```
 server running on port:-3000
started at:-Wed Oct 16 2019 19:38:05 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

hi i am new to node.js but trying to upload a file in my registration page but getting error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileupload' of undefined at 
C:\apiinnodejs\api\app.js:86:21 at Layer.handle_error 
(C:\apiinnodejs\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5) at next 
(C:\apiinnodejs\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:135:13) at Array. 
(C:\apiinnodejs\api\node_modules\Multer\lib\make-middleware.js:53:37) at 
listener (C:\apiinnodejs\api\node_modules\on-finished\index.js:169:15) at 
onFinish (C:\apiinnodejs\api\node_modules\on-finished\index.js:100:5) at 
callback (C:\apiinnodejs\api\node_modules\ee-first\index.js:55:10) at 
IncomingMessage.onevent (C:\apiinnodejs\api\node_modules\ee-first\index.js:93:5) 
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:194:15) at endReadableNT 
(_stream_readable.js:1125:12)emphasized text
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileupload' of undefined

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share what you tried and complete code where you are getting this error: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example